# WXR file - Media import failed - how to force import?

Tags: media, import

Say I have one Wordpress A that I want to move to Wordpress B (different IP addresses, different servers, different subnets). Server A is behind a private IP address.

When selecting export function on Wordpress A, I get a WXR file with all the data including the media.

I understand that, when importing the file on Wordpress B, the import function tries to download the media. However, import of media fails because media are not downloadable.

Even if I copy media manually into the wp-upload folder, the medias are not imported into the post database.

Is there a way to force import all the content (posts of type posts, posts of type medias), even if the corresponding media cannot be downloaded ?

Thanks
++

Comment: it`s a typo or you are doing wrong? is wp-content/uploads, not wp-uploads, you have to copy the uploads folder as it is in the wp-content.

Comment: check the links, are they pointing to the old site, or at the new one.

Comment: There are also wp migration plugins, check Updraftplus for instance